# How to highlight row table using jQuery and cookie?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code for highlighting multi select row in table when click on row in my page.

```
$(".tbl tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("select_rw");
});
```

It's Ok!
But I want to save multi selected row in cookie for highlighting row when I go to another page and back to my page.

Comment: you can keep selected row ids by using cookie

Answer (score 1):

According to hasan proposal,

Here is a kind of implementation that should do the work

I assume you put ids on your  tags

```
$(".tbl tr").click(function(item, i) {

    // get the cookie value
    var selected = $.cookie("store_line");

    // check if is an array and declare it
    if(! Array.isArray(selected)){
      selected = [];
    }

    // push selected id tr 
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));

    // save cookie with new values
    $.cookie("store_line", selected);

    // toogle your class
    $(this).toggleClass("select_rw");
});

// when the page is load, read the cookie and activate row
var selected = $.cookie("store_line");
$.each(selected, function(id){
    $('#' + id).toggleClass("select_rw");
})
```

Comment: this line `if(! Array.isArray(oldValues)){` should be `if(! Array.isArray(selected)){` regards